# Клонирование объекта в PHP

Tags: php

Допустим есть класс Alpha и класс Betta. Объект $b класса Betta содержит переменную $a класса Alpha. При клонировании $b:

```
$c=clone($b);
```

любые операции с объектом $c->$a будут приводить к изменению $b->$a

Но, если вместо clone использовать

```
$c=unserialize(serialize($b));
```

то получится примерно то, что мне нужно ($c->$a и $b->$a - разные объекты).

Мой вопрос: а как правильно делать такое клонирование объекта, когда все переменные внутри нового объекта не связаны с переменными внутри первоначального?

Вот пример кода:

```
            <?php
                function preprint_r($obj){
                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($obj);
                    echo '</pre>';
                }

                class Alpha{
                    var $name = "abc";

                    function __construct($nam){
                        $this->name = $nam;
                    }

                    function change_name($smth){
                        $this->name = $smth;
                    }
                }

                class Betta{
                    var $a;

                    function __construct($nam){
                        $this->a = new Alpha($nam);
                    }

                    //protected //Fatal error: Call to protected method Betta::change_a_name() from context
                    function change_a_name($smth){
                        $this->a->name = $smth;
                    }
                }

                $b = new Betta("zzz");

                //Объект $a внутри $c будет тем же объектом, что и $a внутри $b
                //$c = clone($b);   //
                //Объект $a внутри $c будет отличаться от $a внутри $b
                $c = unserialize(serialize($b));

                preprint_r($b);
                preprint_r($c);

                //$c->a->name = "ccc";
                //$c->a->change_name("xxx");
                $c->change_a_name("eee");

                preprint_r($b);
                preprint_r($c);

            ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этой цели можно использовать магический метод __clone и указать принудительно какие свойства нужно скопировать а иначе они будут являться ссылками на один и тот же объект.

Вот например так:

```
public function __clone()
{
    $this->a = clone $this->a;
}
```